# How can I access Laravel 5.1 validation rules

Tags: php, laravel, validationrules

How can I access all the methods that **Laravel 5.1** provides us for validation. For example I have made custom request with artisan command ***php artisan make:request EventRequest*** in that file there is a public function rules(){ return[]; } in that function yo can specify html attributes names and the validation rules that you need. How can I access these validation rules(path to these rules). **Please note that I don't want to make custom validation rules I have to access existing ones.**

Comment: u want to use rules created in `app\Rules`, in your formRequest class, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you're already aware of the documented [list of available validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#available-validation-rules).

If you just want to access the code that is used to evaluate those rules: in Laravel 5.1, these built-in rule names are mapped to methods defined directly on the [Validator class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php). (You can also check the [API reference for that class](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html))

For example, `'digits_between'` will eventually use the `validateDigitsBetween()` method on that class. However, since those are protected methods, you can't call them directly yourself. You have to use `Validator::make($request, $rules)`. See the [docs on this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#manually-creating-validators).

(In Laravel 5.6, these methods are on a trait called [ValidatesAttributes](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php). So if for whatever reason you wanted to use them directly, you could just use that trait on your class.)

Comment: Trait `ValidatesAttributes` is good, but it uses methods from `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`, and  you have to use `$this->getValidatorInstance()` in your FormRequest class. This method returns `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` and you can use methods of `ValidatesAttributes`.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller replace the `Request` with your validation namespace probably like this  `App\Http\Requests\EventRequest` so it should look like this.

from

```
public function store(Request $requests)
{
   // code here
}
```

to

```
public function store(App\Http\Requests\EventRequest $requests) 
{
   // code here
}
```

or else you can use your validation namespace like so

```
use App\Http\Requests\EventRequest;

SomeControllerClass extends Controller { 
    public function store(EventRequest $requests) 
    {
       // code here
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.